# ReactJs / Javascript - Can a HOC read the parameter component's props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> **I have a Higher Order Component that receives another component as a parameter:**

**HOC**

```
export default function HOC(Comp) {
  return class extends Component {

  doSomething() {
    const temp = // the Comp's clientId prop???
  }
  ........

 }
}
```

---

**Sub Component**

```
@HOC
export default class SubComponent extends Component {    
  .....    

 static proptypes = {
  clientId: PropTypes.string.isRequired
 };

.......    
}
```

**Question:**

Is it possible in the scenario above for the HOC to be aware of SubComponent's clientId property in its arguements and if so, how can I make the HOC aware of it for my doSomething function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's really the HOC that receives the props (or rather the component the function returns), you can just access them with `this.props`:

```
const temp = this.props.clientId;
```

Comment: Working too long today, I see the mistake I made and it baffled me why there was no inheritance when it is obvious there has to be. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't inheritance but composition. But either way, the important part is that the component that is returned from `HOC` receives the props.